# Generate Nested Map from Path String in Java

Tags: java

I want to generate a nested `Map` based on an input path `String` and a `Object` to use at the final inner value.

Here is an example method that uses an example path and rigidly generates the nested `Map` structure:

```
   public Map<String, Object> generateNestedMap(String path, Object value)
   {
      // dot delimited path for the nested map
      path = "foo.bar.baz"; // For example

      // Hard coded nested map generation based on example hard coded path string.
      // Ideally, this should also be much more elegant. 
      Map<String, Object> fooMap = new HashMap<>();
      Map<String, Object> barMap = new HashMap<>();
      Map<String, Object> bazMap = new HashMap<>();
      bazMap.put("baz", value);
      barMap.put("bar", bazMap);
      fooMap.put("foo", barMap);

      return fooMap;
   }
```

Ultimately, I am aiming to generate an arbitrary nested `Map` based on the provided *path* and *value* parameters.

Comment: So what is stopping you from splitting the path on period (using either `split("\\.")`, or an `indexOf('.', idx)` loop) and creating exactly that? --- [I downvoted because no attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/).

Answer (score 2):

The following implementation will do it:

```
public static Map<String, Object> generateNestedMap(String path, Object value) {
    int end = path.length();
    for (int start; (start = path.lastIndexOf('.', end - 1)) != -1; end = start)
        value = new HashMap<>(Collections.singletonMap(path.substring(start + 1, end), value));
    return new HashMap<>(Collections.singletonMap(path.substring(0, end), value));
}
```

*Test*

```
System.out.println(generateNestedMap("foo.bar.baz", 5));
```

*Output*

```
{foo={bar={baz=5}}}
```

---

If you want to add to existing map, so multiple calls are combined, do this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static void generateNestedMap(Map<String, Object> map, String path, Object value) {
    int start = 0;
    for (int end; (end = path.indexOf('.', start)) != -1; start = end + 1)
        map = (Map<String, Object>) map.computeIfAbsent(path.substring(start, end), k -> new HashMap<String, Object>());
    map.put(path.substring(start), value);
}
```

*Test*

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
generateNestedMap(map, "foo.bar.baz", 5);
generateNestedMap(map, "foo.qux.corge", 6);
System.out.println(map);
```

*Output*

```
{foo={bar={baz=5}, qux={corge=6}}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using recursion:-

```
public static Map<String, Object> generateNestedMap(String path, Object value) {
    final int indexOfDot = path.indexOf('.');
    return indexOfDot == -1 ? Collections.singletonMap(path, value)
            : Collections.singletonMap(path.split("\\.")[0],
            generateNestedMap(path.substring(indexOfDot + 1), value));
}
```

Test: `System.out.println(generateNestedMap("foo.bar.baz", "someValue"));`

Output: `{foo={bar={baz=someValue}}}`